# Typescript union types & inferring differing properties without extra type checks

Tags: typescript

I am struggling a bit with union types and am wondering if typescript can infer the value without the extra checks all over the place. Lets say I have this interface setup (left out IBaseDiscount for brevity) where the values can be different but the nested discount type names are fixed

```
interface IFlatDiscount extends IBaseDiscount {
    value:{ formatted: string; value: number };
    discountType: {
        name: DiscountType.flat;
        id: number;
    };
}

interface IOpenDiscount extends IBaseDiscount {
    value?: number;
    discountType: {
        name: DiscountType.open;
        id: number;
    };
}

export interface IPercentageDiscount extends IBaseDiscount {
    value: number;
    discountType: {
        name: DiscountType.percentage;
        id: number;
    };
}

export type IDiscount = IOpenDiscount | IPercentageDiscount | IFlatDiscount;
```

Now in my code when I am trying use these values I end up having to do stuff like the following

```
if (discount.discountType.name === DiscountType.flat && typeof discount.value === 'object) {
    // now my value is properly typed -- if I leave out the object check it doesnt know the correct type for the value
}
```

Is there a proper way for typescript to infer the value based off the discountType.name instead of having all the checks on the value everywhere?

Comment: You want a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#discriminating-unions). Then you can just use a switch statement on the discriminant.

Comment: I know it works on top level properties -- but can it infer from a nested value like that?

Comment: IDK, is there a particular reason you can't either flatten the structure of the interfaces or add a top-level discriminant?

Comment: I mean technically yes but that is the shape that the API is returning and needs to be sent back so I do not want to change it. Was just seeing if I could remove the extra value checks

Comment: Unless I did something wrong, [apparently it can't narrow the type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIHkQoN4FgBQyRyADlAPYkBcyehxDIcAthDQOTlbsEMC+vYlwgALOAGcaYKAFcIBAfgKhIsRClQAVAO7lagomUo06DRizbJ2YXT3pFFDG+TGTk0uQoIEwATxIoAGLkegC8aJgoAD5oOuQA3N74MDIgCGDAXMgARnBQABQAHjTB5ACU+vbI4trAYAgiyEUAdEYkzUysFaZmRAgSKJzcVAa9yAhc4uQANhDN0+QA5i3CrmWJVb3ZUBBwANYbY+MDVs7sI5tmEyBTs-NLLc5rh0c5O-svDl5K+EA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you're doing unnecessary type checking here:

```
if (discount.discountType.name === DiscountType.flat && 
  typeof discount.value === 'object') {
}
```

The following would be enough:

```
if (typeof discount.value === 'object') {
  
}
```

If you want to decide interface according to `discountType.name`, typescript cannot infer type from nested property type checking.

There are basically two ways:

- You use "as" keyword (because you're sure that the type is correct):

```
switch(discount.discountType.name) {
  case DiscountType.flat:
    console.log((discount as IFlatDiscount).value.formatted);
    break;
  case DiscountType.open:
    console.log((discount as IOpenDiscount).value);
    break;
  case DiscountType.percentage:
    console.log((discount as IPercentageDiscount).value);
}
```

- Even better, you can use generic type:

```
export enum DiscountType {
    flat,
    open,
    percentage
}


export interface IGenericDiscount<T extends DiscountType> {
    value: T extends DiscountType.flat 
        ? { formatted: string; value: number } 
        : 
            (T extends DiscountType.open 
                ? (number | undefined) 
                : number
            );
    discountType: {
        name: T;
        id: number;
    }
}

const genericDiscount: IGenericDiscount<DiscountType.open> = JSON.parse('{}');

console.log(genericDiscount.value);
```

[Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBMAdgVwLZwCIEsDOBjCZRGAFQE8xg4BvAWACg4m4AzAGwEMYAaB5uCJUS9GzSlDxIYHAObAGAXwYMsxYFBYdJcAJIAxTjGz5CxGn2YA3Dm2TAAXNVbRUXGMAAm9uDhhRVMgDccNa2DnAoqABG6nAKgRZMHrgERKQU4XSi-EyIHKjhxqnE5JQAdOxcCdk5WF4RaDFQ1fzxisr0qu4aWlQ6APJCRabwWfyhdgD83pFNLczJJmmlmYk5eQXew8sZZYJI8zlwdTON6odx1Ur0DKCQsMdqPdo6AArqksSywNtmY1Y2OynaLnNaLYrpSjef5HDaFFIjFZlcSfaRyC78E4NEHNNZtejXW7gaDwLrqTQvADiSHUWDwvxgAB4SAgQO5EB4cJgETtKAA+cw1CbhFmgdmc7lLEq7SrwNb8SY0ZxQVwwdz1Xz+RBBEKA8KzWIKODy5jeE1HAAUorZSAlDKR+0QxpqRyOiotBqgcAAPnAiB5gCxVJ4AJTO10RuDAprmnIhi7gxEZaGxuHeEgY5hYz0Xa6E+h3ElwGAZXQMuAAXl0gyQ5d9bw+Um+dd0Bi4DOqDAIiF8cETaXsOnLVYAUgBlfoAOWRHCgOGAFoA5NQFIv4x0sCw4BaS5QIFv+8QysLKxWq4uIFEAFbAPAwNeC-iHmDHvXtG70bu9uSIWn0nnEN4OjUr+-j-lKTL2rsjoCqOE7TmAs7zkuK5rp29A-n+DKvmEQA)

Comment: I am going to look into that generic interface you posted ill loop back in on that. I know that technically I can just check object -- but there are potentially going to be more discount types added down the road so just checking for the object could break down the line without anyone noticing

Comment: @topched Always bear in mind that ts is not a runtime type checker. Type checking is your responsibility. Typescript is more like documentation. It helps you not to make mistakes, but it does not prevent it.

Comment: Yeah I know just a little extra piece of mind for other developers + unit tests and helper functions for it. Going to mark this answer as accepted since what I want to do itsnt really possible but this helped clean it up at bit